# Docker Login Gitlab ci/cd

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

this is error , I am using this command in two branch , in branch Master working, but in test branch not working.

```
 echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
```

but not working , what is problem ?

Comment: Is $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD set in both branches?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because your variable isn't shared to a scope with your new branch. You need to add a scope which you new branch is a part of.

[image]

https://gitlab.occ.liberty.edu/help/ci/environments/index#scope-environments-with-specs

You can manage environments by:

1. On the top bar, select Menu > Projects and find your project.
2. On the left sidebar, select Deployments > Environments.